# Extracting a substring after finding a different substring

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I've been playing around with Substring, left, right, charindex and can't quite get this to work

If this is the value in column name `'Data'` (this is all one line)

```
{"email":{"RecipientId":"usertest","RecipientEmail":"test@test.com","Subject":"This is a test subject heading","RecipientSubject":"A recipient subject"}}
```

How do I do a `SELECT` statement to find the `'Subject'` heading and then get the data 'This is a test subject'? The Subject value is different for every record so I just can't look for 'This is a test subject'.

So the end result should be This is a test subject for that `SELECT` result

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014. Using the Query Designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
declare @string varchar(max);
set @string = '{"email":{"RecipientId":"usertest","RecipientEmail":"test@test.com","Subject":"This is a test subject heading","RecipientSubject":"A recipient subject"}}';

select substring(@string,charindex('"Subject":',@string)+11,charindex('"RecipientSubject"',@string)-charindex('"Subject"',@string)-13);
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works well and makes sense going through it step by step

Comment: @user5171795 This might work, but is relying as well on the order as on the existence of both keys. A Json with different key order or a missing one might break this...

Answer (score 1):

The plain and easy-cheesy approach is this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
                 t.YourString
                ,A.StartPosition
                ,CHARINDEX('"'
                          ,t.YourString
                          ,A.StartPosition+1) - A.StartPosition
                 )
FROM @dummyTable t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('"Subject":"',t.YourString)+11) A(StartPosition)
```

I use `APPLY` to calculate a value and use it like you'd use a variable. The idea is: Find the starting point and look for the closing quote from there. But this will break, whenever the content includes an (escaped) quote like in

```
"Subject":"This is \"quoted\" internally"
```

**A more generic approach**

Starting with v2016 JSON-support was introduced. With this (or a higher) version this is really simple:

Use this *mockup-table* for testing

```
DECLARE @dummyTable TABLE (YourString VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @dummyTable VALUES('{"email":{"RecipientId":"usertest","RecipientEmail":"test@test.com","Subject":"This is a test subject heading","RecipientSubject":"A recipient subject"}}');
```

--The `OPENJSON`-method will read this for you:

```
SELECT JsonContent.*
FROM @dummyTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.YourString,'$.email') 
WITH(RecipientId VARCHAR(100)
    ,RecipientEmail VARCHAR(100)
    ,[Subject] VARCHAR(100)
    ,RecipientSubject VARCHAR(100)) JsonContent;
```

But with a lower version you will need to trick this out. It is the easiest, to tranform JSON to *attribute centered XML* like here:

```
<email RecipientId="usertest" RecipientEmail="test@test.com" Subject="This is a test subject heading" RecipientSubject="A recipient subject" />
```

We can achieve this by some string methods and I must warn you, that there are several pit-falls with forbidden characters and other stuff... Just try it out:

```
SELECT Casted.ToXml.value('(/email/@RecipientId)[1]','varchar(1000)') AS RecipientId
      ,Casted.ToXml.value('(/email/@RecipientEmail)[1]','varchar(1000)') AS RecipientEmail
      ,Casted.ToXml.value('(/email/@Subject)[1]','varchar(1000)') AS [Subject]
      ,Casted.ToXml.value('(/email/@RecipientSubject)[1]','varchar(1000)') AS RecipientSubject
      ,Casted.ToXml.query('.') LookHowThisWasTransformed
FROM @dummyTable t 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<email '
                      ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.YourString,'{"email":{"',''),'}}',''),'","','" '),'":"',' ="')
                      ,' />') AS XML)
) Casted(ToXml);
```